# How to pass results from jQuery function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of dropdown options for a survey, and am counting their choices using jquery. The counting code works fine and has been confirmed. The trouble comes with passing the variable to PHP (from what I've read, I'll need to use the POST function but am having trouble) in order to modify the user's meta data based on the survey responses.

Here's the jquery / counting code which works fine:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // get all selects
    var eSelects = $('select.e');

    // set values count by type
    var eyes = 0;

    // for each select increase count
    $.each(eSelects, function(i, s) {
        // increase count
        if($(s).val() == '1') { eyes++; }
    });

    // update count values summary
    $('.cnteyes').text(eyes);
});
```

And here's the PHP which is not working (don't understand how to use the POST function, so left that out):

```
<?php
$response = 'cnteyes';
if ( ! add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'survey', $response, true )) {
   update_user_meta ( get_current_user_id(), 'survey', $response );
}

echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'survey', true );
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm completely stuck and do not understand how to pass jquery to PHP. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use jquery ajax . you can refer this link  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: You should use `JSON`,  `$.ajax()` or `$.getJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data through POST using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
**JS File**
 $.ajax({
    url: "path/to/php/file.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    'someData': 'someData' //you pass your results here
    },
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (result) {
    }
});

**PHP File**

<?php

$someDate = $_POST['someData']; // you access your results here

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// update count values summary
    $('.cnteyes').text(eyes);
```

Above Code should be changed to

```
// update count values summary
    $('.cnteyes').val(eyes);
```

**text()** function just fills the input with the text provided but not the value. But **Val()** function will set the value of the input object to the provided one.

Also on the php snippet the $response should be set to $_POST['cnteyes']

```
<?php
$response = $_POST['cnteyes'];
if ( ! add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'survey', $response, true )) {
   update_user_meta ( get_current_user_id(), 'survey', $response );
}

echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'survey', true );
?>
```

Comment: I guess you are using the form post. else you may need to post the data via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is AJAX, which is asynchronous JavaScript and XML. The answer by @marcus-ekwall [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/1757756) should point you in the right direction, but the short of it is that `POST` and `GET` are ancient pre-JavaScript methods that (among other things) result in page refreshes.

[Tutorials Point introduces AJAX](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm) as follows:

> Conventional web application transmit information to and from the sever using synchronous requests. This means you fill out a form, hit submit, and get directed to a new page with new information from the server.
>
> With AJAX when submit is pressed, JavaScript will make a request to the server, interpret the results and update the current screen. In the purest sense, the user would never know that anything was even transmitted to the server.

You may want to begin by looking at [their PHP and AJAX Example.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**js code**

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // get all selects
    var eSelects = $('select.e');

    // set values count by type
    var eyes = 0;

    // for each select increase count
    $.each(eSelects, function(i, s) {
        // increase count
        if($(s).val() == '1') { eyes++; }
    });
     $.post( 
                  "result.php",
                  { eye: eyes },
                  function(data) {
                      $('.cnteyes').val(eyes);
                  }
               );   
});
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["eye"] ) {

   $response = $_REQUEST['eye'];
  //write your code here.
}
```